# how do I do a find by id if it exists, otherwise do a find_or_initialize_by_columname(params[:somevalue])

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to allow folks to update records directly if they know the id or to put in name/address type of information and it will find the right record or create a new one if it doesn't exist.

`@donor = Donor.find_or_initialize_by_company_and_prefix1_and_first_name1_and_last_name1_and_address1(params[:donor])`

The above works just fine as long as the entered record contains all  the necessary columns (which it will if I am reading this information in via a csv file.)

But now I would like to offer the option of ONLY including an ID and using that if it does exist in the database.  If it doesn't, I would run the above statement to find by those columns or create a new record.

My controller is as follows:

```
      def create
        # need to find donor by id if given, else use find_or_create_by_blahblahblah

        @donor = Donor.find_or_initialize_by_company_and_prefix1_and_first_name1_and_last_name1_and_address1(params[:donor])


        if @donor.new_record?   
          @donor.save
          respond_to do |format|
            if @donor.save
              format.html { redirect_to @donor, notice: 'Donor was successfully created.' }
              format.json { render json: @donor, status: :created, location: @donor }
            else
              format.html { render action: "new" }
              format.json { render json: @donor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end    
        else
          respond_to do |format|
            if @donor.save
              format.html { redirect_to @donor, notice: 'Donor already exists.  Please edit donor if needed.'}
              format.json { render json: @donor, status: :created, location: @donor }
            else
              format.html { render action: "new" }
              format.json { render json: @donor.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end 
        end   

      end
```

I am having trouble finding what to do if an ID is supplied to check it.

I tried something like:

```
@donor = Donor.find_by_id(params[:donor])
if !@donor
   @donor = Donor.find_or_initialize_by_all_those_columns(params[:donor])
end
```

but this gives me an error if I put data in, say for example, the company field instead of only the ID field.

I am sure there is a slick way to do this that I just haven't seen yet.  Any help on it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
unless @donor = Donor.find_by_id(params[:donor][:id]) // returns `nil` if record not found
    @donor = Donor.find_or_initialize_by_all_those_columns(params[:donor])
end

@donor.new_record? ...
```

The first line looks for a record with the ID passed in. If it returns a record, then `@donor` is set to that record and the block is not run. If not, then it will return `nil` (using `find_by_id()` instead of `find()` is important for this reason, because `find()` raises an error if no record is found), and the block will be run, setting `@donor` to a record (new or not) with the params.

Hopefully this answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

If the record already exists you would typically route the form submission to the `update` action of your controller.

Nevertheless, if you want to handle the situation in the `create` action you simply need to know which parameter has the donor id.  I'll take a guess and say that it might `params[:donor][:id]`.  If that's the case then this would work:

```
@donor = Donor.find_by_id(params[:donor][:id])
```

Take a look at your form parameters to find out the correct name.